# Does all linux distros Support bash aliases?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, kali-linux, distributions

There's a feature of bash aliases in Kali Linux.

1. So I want to know if other linux distros like Linux Mint also support this?
   If yes then how to do that?
2. Are bash aliases similar to .bat files in windows? If no then is there a way to create .bat type of files in linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1a) Aliases (managed with the `alias` command) are a feature of `bash` itself, not of any distro. So all distros will support `bash` aliases.

1b) They work in the same way on all distros, with the `alias` command.

2a) No, `.bat` files on Windows correspond to **shell scripts** on Linux systems (all distros).

2b) Yes, you can create them with any text editor. Google "shell script" for details.

3) If you are new to Linux, I really really recommend **not** using Kali. Kali is meant for [penetration testing](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), not for learning Linux, for hacking, or for daily work. Kali is **not** "what all the hackers use", no matter what you read on some forums. Nobody really uses Kali (except for penetration testing).

Get some other distribution (stay with a Debian-based one, e.g. Ubuntu; Kali is also Debian-based), and you'll have all the hacking tools Kali has, but none of the trouble.